# Android horizontal preloader

Tags: android, android-animation

Hi I want to add a horizontal dotted preloader I cant add any image due to less reputation but for reference it should be like  **....**....
I added a gif image in my code  but it only shows blank white screen. kindly let me know how to achieve this thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you add the gif image? The last time I tried using a gif for that, I created a class which extends to view then added the following:

```
public class Splash extends View {

    private Movie movie;
    private long movieStart;

public Splash(Context context) {
        super(context);
        InputStream is = getContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.splash);
        movie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        if (movieStart == 0) {
            movieStart = now;
        }
        if (movie != null) {
            int relTime = (int) ((now - movieStart) % movie.duration());
            movie.setTime(relTime);
            movie.draw(canvas, (getWidth() - movie.width()) / 2, (getHeight() - movie.height()) / 2);
            this.invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Use this class as your view on your loading activity.

```
Splash splashUI = new Splash(YourActivity.this);
setContentView(splashUI);
```

Then for on your Manifest:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

on the activity for your loading.

Comment: can you please provide me the full code.. coz i dont know the valeue of **movieStart** and how where to put this code in the class
[InputStream is = getContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.splash);
Movie movie = Movie.decodeStream(is);]
thanks